# SQL query select top 5 per group leading Access to freeze on simple code and small data

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I was trying to reproduce the select top n from group SQL but access freezes (**takes minutes to complete**) even on small set of data.

```
date         ret1         anndate

26-Jul-13   0.999214    25-Jul-13
29-Jul-13   0.982684    25-Jul-13
30-Jul-13   0.947938    25-Jul-13
31-Jul-13   1.024081    25-Jul-13
01-Aug-13   1.017739    25-Jul-13
02-Aug-13   1.001621    25-Jul-13
10-Dec-13   0.965405    09-Dec-13
11-Dec-13   1.009705    09-Dec-13
12-Dec-13   1.025508    09-Dec-13
13-Dec-13   0.994232    09-Dec-13
16-Dec-13   1.009065    09-Dec-13
17-Dec-13   0.984549    09-Dec-13
18-Dec-13   1.007299    09-Dec-13
```

What I wanted to achieve is to have the five following rows per each 'anndate'. for example, for anndate 25 july 2013, I want the first 5 rows. for anndate 09-dec-2013, I want 5 following rows ended on 16-dec-2013.

my code is:

```
SELECT *
FROM com
WHERE date in 
(select top 5 date from com where com.date>com.anndate);
```

but it causes access to crash(**correction: should be 'take minutes to complete'**). Anyone can help point out where is wrong?

**update:**

I changed the column name [date] to [cdate], it still doesnt work.

I ran **something simple like below and it still takes minutes to complete....**

```
SELECT *
FROM com
WHERE cdate in (select cdate from com )
```

Comment: What does `crash` mean? does it throw an error?  Perhaps its an error that looks like `date` is a reserved word and you need to bracket your column names?

Comment: @paqogomez . . . The first sentence says that Access freezes.

Comment: Date is a reserved word in Access. It can be used if you enclose it in []'s but it's not a recommended practice. Not sure if this is your issue, but it's definitely something you might consider changing.

Comment: If you have been working for a while, and especially if you have not split your database, it is a good idea to compact & repair and decompile.

Comment: Thank you all for replying. sorry for the confusion. what I meant is Access was not responding. I changed the column name but it still doesn't work. @fionnuala I tried compact & repair but still the same....

Comment: @GordonLinoff .... The last sentence said that it causes Access to crash.  Thank you OP for clarification.

Comment: When you run other queries - how does it act?

Comment: other queries work fine, completed in just a few seconds. I guess the IN clause + correlated subquery is the culprit. I didn't expect it would be so slow....

Comment: Your clause `WHERE date in (select top 5 date from com where com.date>com.anndate);` is non-deterministic.  `TOP` requires an `ORDER BY`, or the rows will not be returned in any specific order.  Try `(SELECT TOP 5 date FROM com WHERE com.date > com.anndate ORDER BY com.date DESC)`.  Also, make sure an index exists on `com.date`.

Comment: Actually, I don't even think your query does what you're saying you want.  I think this might: `SELECT * FROM com AS c WHERE date IN (SELECT TOP 5 date FROM com WHERE anndate = c.anndate ORDER BY date DESC);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stored your sample data in a table with both `date` and `anndate` as Date/Time data type.  Then I built a query with `anndate_rank` generated from a correlated subquery.  The purpose of `anndate_rank` is a rank number within each `anndate` group.

Then that entire query became a subquery in a new one which selects `anndate_rank` <= the top limit --- I chose top 2 instead of top 5.

This is the result set from the query, and the query is below:

```
date       ret1     anndate   anndate_rank
---------- -------- --------- ------------
7/26/2013  0.999214 7/25/2013            1
7/29/2013  0.982684 7/25/2013            2
12/10/2013 0.965405 12/9/2013            1
12/11/2013 1.009705 12/9/2013            2
```

```sql
SELECT
    sub.date,
    sub.ret1,
    sub.anndate,
    sub.anndate_rank
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.date,
            c.ret1,
            c.anndate,
            (
                SELECT Count(*)
                FROM com AS c2
                WHERE
                        c2.anndate=c.anndate
                    AND c2.date<=c.date
            ) AS anndate_rank
        FROM com AS c
    ) AS sub
WHERE sub.anndate_rank<=2;
```

Note this approach assumes no repeated `date` values within any `anndate` group, as in your sample data.  If your real data does include duplicate `date` / `anndate` pairs, this query will not give you the results you want.

Comment: Hi Hansup, thank you very much for the help. Your query definitely achieved what I was looking for. However, the performance of it for a large data set is still not very good. I was wondering if this is the best performing algorithm for top N per group problem in Access. If so, will changing the data type from Date to Number improve the performance? Thanks again.

Comment: Ensure both `date` and `anndate` are indexed.  If they are and performance is still unsatisfactory, I have nothing else to offer.  Date/Time is actually a numeric datatype already --- double precision float --- so I doubt changing the datatype would result in a significant performance improvement.  If you want to try another type, use Long Integer since it seems you're only interested in the date component, not the time component.