# MS Access - Identify highest 3 values across columns

Tags: ms-access

I have a table containing data like the following:

```
ID    Team1    Team2    Team3    Team4    Team5    Team6
1     5        0        1        2        3        1
3     1        4        0        2        4        1
5     0        0        4        2        1        1
6     4        1        1        2        0        0
```

I want to derive 3 new columns from this data with the 1st, 2nd and 3rd highest values from across all the columns, like so:

```
ID    Team1    Team2    Team3    Team4    Team5    Team6   Top1  Top2   Top3
1     5        0        1        2        3        1       5      3      2
3     1        4        0        2        4        1       4      4      2
5     0        0        4        2        1        1       4      2      1
6     4        1        1        2        0        0       4      2      1
```

Is this possible in Access? I want to rank them so that equal values are ranked incrementally, for example:

```
ID     Value   Rank
3      4       1
3      4       2
3      2       3
3      1       4
3      1       5
```

I'm open to using VBA if there is a way to achieve it through that means. The data is also available unpivoted if it's easier to pull out the top 3 values in that format.

Sample of unpivoted data:

```
ID    Team    Score
1     Team1   5
1     Team3   1
1     Team4   2
1     Team5   3
1     Team6   1
3     Team1   5
3     Team2   4
3     Team4   2
3     Team5   4
3     Team1   1
```

Comment: It **would** be much easier from the unpivoted data, can you append sample data to your question?

Comment: Sample unpivoted data added above

Comment: This is one of those queries that sound easy but aren't. Check out this search and see if you can adapt a solution: [select top n per group](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+select+top+n+per+group), especially http://stackoverflow.com/a/26812786/3820271

Comment: Thanks, that link gets me almost there but I need to rank my duplicate values incrementally (so 4,4 would be ranked 1,2; rather than 1,1)

Answer (score 0):

Take this function (from [Finding Max of 3 Inputs VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460366/finding-max-of-3-inputs-vba))

```
Sub Maxthree()  
'Calculates the maximum of three numbers'  
Dim x, y, z As Single  
x = InputBox("Enter the first number!")  
y = InputBox("Enter the second number!")  
z = InputBox("Enter the third number!")  
MsgBox ("X: " & x & " Y: " & y & " Z: " & z)  
If x > y Then  
    If x > z Then  
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & x)  
    Else
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & z)  
    End If  
Else  
    If y > z Then  
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & y)  
    Else  
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & z)  
    End If  
End If  
End Sub
```

Adjust it to return the highest value (rather than display it in a msgbox). construct two additional functions to get the second and third value.

Use those function in an Sql query to the columns you want,

Good luck.